# How can I search for specific words in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: javascript, string

I have a collection that contains two documents:
name
content

the content contains long texts and what I want to do is I want to search for a specific word in my documents (just inside the content field) and get its name and index.

For example:

```
id:619c10
name: papers
content: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 


id:619c20
name: Stone
content: stie nunc non blandit massa. **Neque** egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus. Commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum. Arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam. Commodo viverra maecenas
```

For example, the word I'm looking for is **"Neque"** which is in the second document.
I want to get this:
name Stone
Index: 27

I used regex but I don't know what should I do with the response to get name and index.

```
Subtitle.find({ content: { $regex: 'Neque', $options: 'i' } }, (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to index the content field to be able to perform search queries ,
read this : [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#:~:text=MongoDB%20supports%20query%20operations%20that,index%20and%20the%20%24text%20operator.&text=Views%20do%20not%20support%20text%20search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#:%7E:text=MongoDB%20supports%20query%20operations%20that,index%20and%20the%20%24text%20operator.&text=Views%20do%20not%20support%20text%20search).